# Call a macro within a macro parameter of another macro

Tags: sas, macros

I have a macro that does lots of calculations.
This macro needs to be repeated for many variables in a do loop.
The below is a mock-up (as actual macro is too long).
In the example below %macone is the macro that does all the calculations. This macro
needs to be called as parameter for %mactwo.
I want to be able to called mactwo and be able to modify the parameters with macone.

```
%macro macone(val=);
 %put &val;
%mend macone;



%let lista=vara varb;
%let listb=varc vard;

%macro mactwo(callmac);
    %let n = %sysfunc(countw(&lista));
    %let v = %sysfunc(countw(&listb));
    %do c=1 %to &n;
        %let nlist = %scan(&lista , &c);
        %do p=1 %to &v;
            %let npop = %scan(&listb , &p);
         &callmac;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend mactwo;

%mactwo(%macone(hello world));
```

Comment: Not a good example as %MACONE() does not EMIT any code to pass as the input to %MACTWO().   Do you have an actual use case?  And if so why not just introduce a macro variable? `%let mvar=%macone(...);  %mactwo(&mvar)`

Comment: You may want to let `val` be a position parameter, not a named parameter: `%macro macone(val);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass macro CODE as the input then protect it.  You could use actual quotes.

```
%mactwo('%macone()')
```

Then inside of MACTWO you could remove them.

```
%sysfunc(dequote(&callmac))
```

Or you could assume the input is a macro call and so not bother to try to pass in the % as part of the value being passed.

```
%mactwo(macone())
```

You can then add the % to trigger the macro processor when you use the value in the outer macro.

```
 %&callmac
```

Comment: Great trick: `%&callmac`. I once had a very painful time learning macro quoting functions.

Answer (score 2):

mactwo appears to be functioning in the role of a combinatoric dispatcher.

A clearer approach could be using a DATA Step as the dispatcher that does the nested loop cross join and invokes the unit of work macro via `call execute()`

Example:

```
%macro worker(arg1, var1, var2);
  %put NOTE: &=arg1 &=var1 &=var2;
%mend;

data _null_ ;
  list1 = 'vara varb';
  list2 = 'varc vard';
  do i = 1 to countw(list1);
    var1 = scan(list1,i);
    do j = 1 to countw(list2);
      var2 = scan(list2,j);
      call execute( '%nrstr(%worker)(' || catx(',','Hello world',var1,var2) || ')' );
    end;
  end;
run ;
```

Will log the 4 pairwise combinations:

```
...
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + %worker(Hello world,vara,varc)
NOTE: ARG1=Hello world VAR1=vara VAR2=varc
2   + %worker(Hello world,vara,vard)
NOTE: ARG1=Hello world VAR1=vara VAR2=vard
3   + %worker(Hello world,varb,varc)
NOTE: ARG1=Hello world VAR1=varb VAR2=varc
4   + %worker(Hello world,varb,vard)
NOTE: ARG1=Hello world VAR1=varb VAR2=vard
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may located at the execution order of macros:
As I run(add a `%put` statement):

```
%macro macone(val);
 %put &val;
%mend macone;

%let lista=vara varb;
%let listb=varc vard;

%macro mactwo(callmac);
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&lista));
%let v = %sysfunc(countw(&listb));
  %do c=1 %to &n;
  %let nlist = %scan(&lista , &c);
    %do p=1 %to &v;
      %let npop = %scan(&listb , &p);
      %put &=c &=p;
      &callmac;
    %end;
  %end;
%mend mactwo;

%mactwo(%macone(hello world));
```

The log window shows:

```
hello world
C=1 P=1
C=1 P=2
C=2 P=1
C=2 P=2
```

Although I write the `%put &=c &=p` statement before, `%macone(hello world)` is executed earlier than that statement. So we need to delay its execution, to bring it into the loop.

```
%macro mactwo(callmac);
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&lista));
%let v = %sysfunc(countw(&listb));
  %do c=1 %to &n;
  %let nlist = %scan(&lista , &c);
    %do p=1 %to &v;
      %let npop = %scan(&listb , &p);
      %put &=c &=p;
      %unquote(&callmac);
    %end;
  %end;
%mend mactwo;

%mactwo(%nrstr(%macone(hello world)));
```

Please note the usage of `%nrstr()` and `%unquote()`. Now the log window shows:

```
C=1 P=1
hello world
C=1 P=2
hello world
C=2 P=1
hello world
C=2 P=2
hello world
```

Comment: This worked nicely... Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't understand how that solution relates to your statement 'I want to be able to call mactwo and be able to modify the parameters with macone.'.  If all you want to do is pass parameters between macros (which I don't see being done here), there are much easier ways to do this, that don't require passing a macro call as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure of your question. If your goal is to have mactwo call macone inside a loop and pass values to it, you don't need to actually call macone as a parameter, you can do it like:

```
%macro macone(nlist=,npop=);
 %put ;
 %put [&sysmacroname] Hello I am macone ;
 %put [&sysmacroname] &=nlist &=npop;
%mend macone;

%macro mactwo(lista=,listb=);   
%local n v c p nlist npop ;
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&lista));
%let v = %sysfunc(countw(&listb));
  %do c=1 %to &n;
  %let nlist = %scan(&lista , &c);
    %do p=1 %to &v;
      %let npop = %scan(&listb , &p);
      %put ;
      %put [&sysmacroname] Hello I am mactwo ;
      %put [&sysmacroname] &=c &=p &=nlist &=npop;
      %macone(nlist=&nlist,npop=&npop)
    %end;
  %end;
%mend mactwo;

%mactwo(lista=vara varb,listb=varc vard)
```